# PC doesn't detect external USB hard drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, desktop-computer, hardware-detection

My PC doesn't detect an external USB hard drive. The weird thing is that the power LED is on which should mean that everything is okay. I tried it on different ports and it still can't be detected. I thought it's a problem with the hard drive itself so I tried another hard drive but got same result. I tried the hard drive on my friends laptop and it did detected normally.

So is there something blocking my PC from detecting it? I did a search but couldn't find anything. It's like the USB isn't plugged at all.

Comment: Please provide details if you want help - for example OS, what you mean by "did a search" and disk size and brands. Have you tried updating USB drivers, and what happens if you try plug in pen drives?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on disk management (win+r and type in diskmgmt.msc) and see if it's listed there. If it is, highlight its partition and click "Change drive letter and paths", add a letter to it and it should pop up in explorer now. Your problem may be that your pc doesn't automount new drives. To fix that, open up cmd with admin, type in "diskpart", then "automount". It will tell you if it's on or off. To toggle it, type in "automount enable" or "automount disable"